# Assign a variable to the result of a call inside a coroutine

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, coroutinescope

Is there a one-liner for this?

```
...
var x = ""
coroutine.launch {
    x = StoreHelper.getProductPrice(mdProducts[0].id)
}
return x
```

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57330766/why-does-my-function-that-calls-an-api-or-launches-a-coroutine-return-an-empty-o

Comment: This doesn't work like you think it does, so you should not look for a one-liner for it. What are you trying to achieve here? Just call `getProductPrice` if you want to get the value in a way that looks synchronous

Comment: Correct, Tenfour, it's a dupe; and correct Joffrey, that was wishful thinking code. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't rely that variable `x` will have a different value apart from `""` in that case. Coroutines run asynchronously, so the `x` can be returned with value `""` before the code `StoreHelper.getProductPrice()` runs.

You can rewrite the code to something like the following:

```
coroutine.launch {
    val x = StoreHelper.getProductPrice(mdProducts[0].id)
    // do smth with x
}
```

but you can't return `x` from the function in this case.

And as per my knowledge there is no one-liner for that.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use `async` instead, which returns a [`Deferred`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-deferred/)

```
return coroutine.async { StoreHelper.getProductPrice(mdProducts[0].id) }
```

and later you can `await` the result in a coroutine - or if you want to use the experimental `getCompleted` function and hope it's completed, you can do that. Not the best idea for handling an asynchronous result though, `await` is what you should really be using.

Bear in mind that this is the whole issue with async code - stuff happens simultaneously, some things take longer than others, so you need a way to handle the results *when they're ready*. You can't return `x` until you have it, so you either need to block until the coroutine finishes, or return something like the `Deferred` (which is like a Java `Future`) so you have a reference to the running job you can check later. Or don't return a result at all, and just have that job *do something* when it's finished, like calling a function.

[This section on async functions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/composing-suspending-functions.html#concurrent-using-async) might be helpful to look through, to give you some ideas about what you need and what you can do.

Comment: Thank you @cactus, this was delusional. For the time being, I replaced by a poor-man's "solution": return runBlocking { StoreHelper.getProductPrice(mdProducts[0].id) } Question: is Deferred considered good form? I see it all over my code (which was written by a Java convert to Kotlin)

Comment: @YanayLehavi the examples in the link deal with a `Deferred` - it's the result of calling the `async` function, and you use `await()` to suspend the current coroutine until the result of the `async` coroutine arrives. It's a standard way to uh, *await* a result that you need. It's definitely better than `runBlocking` which is generally for things like `main` functions, so it can put the entire program inside a coroutine and block the thread from doing anything else, and shouldn't be called *inside* a coroutine (as per the `runBlocking` doc page)